# Mysql column count multiplies

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two correct mysql query like this:

```
select 
count(aboneler.abone_isim),
nas.nasname

from nas
left join aboneler on ( aboneler.nas = nas.id )

group by nas.nasname
```

[firt query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUxL6.png)
and

```
select 
count(radacct.radacctid)

from nas
left join radacct on ( radacct.nasipaddress = nas.nasname )
where radacct.acctstoptime is null

group by nas.nasname
```

[second query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkRnr.png) 
but if i put together this two query i get this:

```
select 
nas.nasname,
count(aboneler.abone_isim),
count(radacct.radacctid)

from nas
left join aboneler on ( aboneler.nas = nas.id )
left join radacct on ( radacct.nasipaddress = nas.nasname )
where radacct.acctstoptime is null

group by nas.nasname
```

[last query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kA2M.png) it shouldn't be like this. I hope I could explain my problem.

Comment: Just for clearing it up: aboneler means 'subscribers'? Also what's the radacct table; is it a log of ip addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below way -

```
select A.nasname,cnt1,cnt2 from
(
select nas.nasname,count(aboneler.abone_isim) as cnt1
from nas
left join aboneler on aboneler.nas = nas.id 
group by nas.nasname
)A join 
(
select nas.nasname,count(radacct.radacctid) as cnt2
from nas left join radacct on ( radacct.nasipaddress = nas.nasname )
where radacct.acctstoptime is null
group by nas.nasname
) B on A.nasname=B.nasname
```